# Flipping 2 fair coins

Tags: probability-theory

If you are flipping 2 fair coins, what is more likely to come up sooner on one of the coins, TT or TH?
The professor says it is not a probability question.

Comment: How can one coin get TT?

Comment: Do you mean that on one of the coins two consecutive tosses yields T followed by T for the first case and T followed by H for the second case?

Comment: one is flipped until TH appears and another until TT appears. Which will appear sooner (with fewer flips)? Since these are indpendent events, I don't see how they are not equally likely.

Comment: This is obviously a probability question.

Comment: It seems to be equal, the probability that is.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, as soon as one T appears, the next flip is equally likely to be a T or an H, so neither is more likely to appear before the other.

Answer (score 0):

We change the question, to what is more likely to appear first, TT or HT. If We get TT at the beginning (probability $\frac{1}{4}$, then TT wins. In all other cases, HT wins.

(For the original question, TT and TH are equally likely to be first.)